# Remove string from list using ((Button)v).getText().toString()

Tags: android, button, arraylist

What am i missing, i have some code similar to:

```
    ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    myList.add("hello")
    btn.setText("hello");
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String removeThisString = ((Button)v).getText().toString();
            myList.remove(removeThisString);
        }
    });
```

But it doesn't work so i have to be missing something. Is my string removeThisStrings equals method obscured because of the string extraction from the button? Strings should already have an equals method on them that should let me compare them, which the remove method uses.

I added a log, and removeThisString is indeed = to "hello" and myList = ["hello"]. And myList.contains(removeThisString) is false so even though they look the same they arent somehow.

If i would do `myList.remove("hello");` than it would work. Is there a way i can check the strings equal implementation.

Comment: No, you can remove by object as well.

Comment: `List` doesn't compare contents only the reference value.  Because you passed your "string" through the `toString` method, this is no longer representing the "same" string as far as Java's reference-equality is concerned.  There's nothing wrong with the `String` implementation, but you may consider the `List` has issues.  Also, `Button.getText` returns a `CharSequence` not a `String`, hence the need to call `toString`.  The two literal copies of "hello" are the same reference; Java always makes those "equal".  There's rules for when strings are the same reference or not (copy-on-write).

Comment: I see, so this implementation is not possible? I guess i will have to revert to use a final string again.

Comment: You can search the list by contents, then use its index to `remove` or use the `Iterator.remove`.  You can verify the strings are different by dumping out their `getHashCode` values; they should be different.  Same problem exists when using your own classes, and "equality" must be decided by "memberwise comparison" this is common for so-called "value" objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArrayList works like an array in the sense that it can get an item by it's index which an int. In this case, adding the first item to myList "hello" is at index 0. So in your code it would be:

1. Simple Explicit Indexing

   ```
   ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
   myList.add("hello")
   btn.setText("hello");
   btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
          String removeThisString = btn.getText().toString();
          myList.remove(0);
       }
   });
   ```
2. OR a conditional solution:

   ```
   ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
   myList.add("hello")
   btn.setText("hello");
   btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
          String removeThisString = btn.getText().toString();
           if (removeThisString.equals(myList.get(0))) {
               myList.remove(0);
           }
       }
   });
   ```
3. OR a conditional and a more dynamic solution:

   ```
   final ArrayList<String> myList =  new ArrayList<>();
   myList.add("hello");
   btn.setText("hello");


   btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           String removeThisString = ((Button)v).getText().toString();
           if (myList.size() > 0) {

               for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
                   if (removeThisString.equals(myList.get(i))) {
                       myList.remove(i);
                   }
               }
           } else {
               ((Button)v).setText("Array List is empty");
           }
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: Yes, i thought about saving the index and use that to remove it, but that would really need much change in my code. The problem is that i cannot use equal on the list element with the removeThisString , i.e. this wont equal true > removeThisString.equals(myList.get(0))   . As  escape-llc pointed out in the comments, its not that simple :(.

Comment: Sorry my edits were not showing before, please take a look at no. 3, you need a more conditional and dynamic solution

Comment: @user3711421 "this wont equal true > removeThisString.equ‌​als(myList.get(0)) "...YES it will! I just tested it. Please try the solution, let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Are you trying to get a button by the view id?

Comment: 1 up for working code but my question was on how to do this using the data provided by View v (button), not directly using btn.getText(). Maybe it will be similar in your code though? I dont have access to btn variable and would rather leave out a list to keep track of all the buttons textual information.

Comment: Three questions: 1. do you have several buttons in this view or 1? 2. is the button defined in your xml? 3. Is this inside a fragment or an activity?

Comment: 1. The buttons are created programmatically, so yes, there could be several buttons in the view, i.e. user presses an addNewButton button - which will create a new button and add it to the view.  2. Nope 3. Fragment...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121095/discussion-between-andrew-el-masry-and-user3711421).

Comment: All you need is a for loop. I updated number 3. This should be exactly what you need, it gets the text of any button clicked and runs a for loop to see if it matches any entries in the ArrayList